# SUMIFS within VBA showing "Unable to get the SumIfs property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code where

- range_sum_result = C15 (this is where I want to place the result of my sum)
- range_to_sum = C2:C14 (this is the range with values I want to sum)
- range_date_search = B2:B15 (this is a column that contains dates I want to compare against)
- Start_date_range = 22/07/2021
- End_date_range = 28/07/2021 23:59:59

  ```
    'SUMIFS
    Worksheets("Data_Graph2").Range(range_sum_result).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range(range_to_sum), Range(range_date_search), ">=" & Start_date_range, Range(range_date_search), "<=" & End_date_range)
  ```

I have declared Start_date_range and End_date_range as dates.

why is this not working?

@BigBen was right, the range_date_search should have been B2:B15

I have corrected that but now the result is 0

I am trying to replicate the following formula

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C14,$B2:$B14,">=" &$A$15, $B2:$B14, "<=" &$B$15)
```

why is the VBA version not giving the same results?

Comment: `range_to_sum` and `range_date_search` don't have the same number of rows.

Comment: make it `B2:B14` as @BigBen says.

Comment: According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumifs), the sum_range (1st argument) and the criteria_range (2nd argument) do not have to be the same size.  I think that the problem is that one of your criteria arguments (arg 4) is a multi-cell range (`Range(range_date_search)`) but according to the doc, the criteria list only accepts values, expressions, text and cell references (i.e., *not* range/multi-cell references).

Comment: @RBarryYoung - a regular `=SUMIFS(C2:C14,B2:B15,"foo")` bombs out in a worksheet so not quite sure that's right. Also arg 4 is a criteria range. Actually the docs are just wrong on the args. It goes `criteria_range, criteria, criteria_range2, criteria2...` Yay for MSFT documentation.

Comment: @RBarryYoung it actually works now (the size of the range was indeed wrong) but now it returns 0 and I believe it might be because of your comment.

I want to create something that is the equivalent of this 

=SUMIFS(C2:C14,$B2:$B14,">=" &$A$15, $B2:$B14, "<=" &$B$15)

Comment: @BigBen You may be right. The VBA Excel model doc has never been that great.

Comment: @RBarryYoung can you help me figure out why it is returning 0 now that I have adjusted the ranges? I have added more information to the description of the question.

Comment: Honestly no idea beyond what I've already posted.  I never use WorksheetFunctions from VBA, I just write my own VBA functions to do what I want (because they're faster and they work the way I expect and don't do weird inexplicable stuff like this).

Comment: @RBarryYoung I tried doing that but the code became so complex and it was such a mess that I decided to try to use SUMIFS instead

Comment: Does wrapping `Start_date_range` and `End_date_range` in `CDbl` work?

Comment: @BigBen I wrapped them in CLng and it worked

Comment: `CLng` will get rid of any time component, i.e. you really don't want to use `CLng` with `28/07/2021 23:59:59`. i.e. in the Immediate Window, `? Clng(DateValue("28/07/2021")+TimeValue("23:59:59"))` returns `44406`, and `? CDbl(DateValue("28/07/2021")+TimeValue("23:59:59"))` returns `44405.9999884259`

Comment: Or use `CLng` and change the `<=` to `<` in your formula.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for this! I was having an issue where it was counting an extra number on one of the columns and by changing it to CDbl it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adjusting the ranges of range_to_sum and range_date_search as BigBen sugested, the following formula made it work.

```
  Worksheets("Data_Graph2").Range(range_sum_result).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range(range_to_sum), Range(range_date_search), ">=" & CDbl(Start_date_range), Range(range_date_search), "<=" & CDbl(End_date_range))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a valid result with this code:

```
 Dim Start_date_range As Date
 Dim End_date_range As Date
 Dim range_sum_result As Range
 Dim range_to_sum As Range
 Dim range_date_search As Range
 
 
Set range_sum_result = Range("C15")
Set range_to_sum = Range("C2:C14")
Set range_date_search = Range("B2:B14")
 
Start_date_range = Date - 1
End_date_range = Date + 1


range_sum_result.Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(range_to_sum, range_date_search, ">=" & Start_date_range, range_date_search, "<=" & End_date_range)
```

Comment: If you can explain why then this would be a good answer.